# What am I doing wrong with this Windows 7 FTP script?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, ftp

I am trying to create a text file (`commands.txt`) for FTP in Windows 7.

The file looks like this...

```
open 10.10.10.12 9999
USER anonymous
anonymous
GET file1.txt
bye
```

I then jump to a Command Prompt(administrative) and change directories to where my `commands.txt` file resides; I check it with `dir` command.

Then I run...

```
C:\Users\User1\Scripts>ftp.exe -v -n -s:commands.txt
```

The terminal then shows me the help output for ftp.
I'm stumped to what I'm doing wrong here and I can't use a batch file for this, GUIs, or here-documents. Even if I could, it seems like this SHOULD work and it's killing me not knowing what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What encoding did you save the file with? No BOM?

Comment: Most command-line tools/commands show you help when you use invalid arguments. I have tried creating your commands.txt and running the command you specified and it tries to connect. Maybe you mistyped the filename or are in anothed directory, ftp.exe shows help when it can't find the file.

Comment: Note: In Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 or later operating systems, the text file must be written in UTF-8. Maybe even in windows 7. Check it...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. Shout-out to @LotPings for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem was with the way both notepad and the command prompt were encoding the characters.

Had to follow this advice...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598785/save-text-file-in-utf-8-encoding-using-cmd-exe

The answer was to change the code page using the `chcp` command.

Apparently my Windows7 box was encoding the file in a format that wasn't supported by ftp. Oddly, using the command prompt to echo the commands into a file suffered from the same problem.

I then used the chcp command

`chcp 65001`

This changes the encoding to UTF-8, then echo my commands into a file, then run ftp

`ftp.exe -v -n -s:commands.txt`

and I was golden.

I then changed back to code page 1252

```
chcp 1252
```

and all was right with the world.

Thanks for the help all!